# how to include ID in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

my selenium script show only `find_element_by_css_selector`

how to include `find_element_by_id`

it throws attribute error

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import shutil
import sys
import time
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import random

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
br = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

login=br.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div > div > newpage > submitbtn') login.click() 

new=br.find_element_by_id('buttonname') new.click()
```

Comment: what is the error shown by python?

Comment: Please include some code in your question

Comment: login=br.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div > div > newpage > submitbtn')
login.click()

Comment: now i want to select a button
for this 
new=br.find_element_by_id('buttonname') 
new.click() 
but it throws error like attribute cannot find find_element_by_id
how to  solve this

Comment: Edit your original post with the entire code please. Including imports

Comment: these are the imports using 
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import shutil
import sys
import time
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import random

Comment: in script it showing only option 
find_element_by_css_selector
no other elements
how to include that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you dont share the HTML it is quite difficult ot answer but you have to use id using `find_element_by_id`

```
login=br.find_element_by_id('value of id button') login.click()
```

Comment: issue is find_element_by_id not showing in my script

i type find_   in script

only option i see is 
find_element_by_id

Comment: Strange :( :(:(

Comment: chrome extension have any limitation?"
only option showing is find_element_by_css_selector

no id,name,xpath etc..

Comment: May be I did not faced any issue like that, try with other browser and see

Comment: how ? in script ?

Comment: use firefoxdriver

Comment: yes i tried. issue is it stops in login page

not going further

Comment: Please share the HTML, so we can investigate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160420/discussion-between-iamsankalp89-and-jim).